# SQL - how to use row value as ColumnName?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to use a static row value from one of the tables I'm calling to be used as a part of the column name in the results table.  The SQL is being written against a DB2 table (which has its own picky SQL nuances and syntax).

---

```
select 
s.student_number, s.name,
r.registration_status as reg_sts || r.session_d,
r1.registration_status as reg_sts || r1.session_cd

from student_nums s, registration_status r

left join registration_status r1 on
(r.student_number = r1.student_numer
and r1.session_cd = 
(case r.session_cd when ‘fall’
Then ‘winter’
When ‘winter’
Then ‘spring’
When ‘summer’
Then ‘fall’
Else ‘ ‘
End))

Where 
s.student_number = r.student_number
And r.session_cd = &session_cd
```

---

Trying to concatenate text with the rowvalue to generate a ColumnName fails.
(**e.g.  r.registration_status as reg_sts || r.session_d**).  Can I generate a ColumnName that isn't just a text string I provide?
Tips?  Thanks in advance.

---

You can see that the r.session_cd in the primary registration table being called is a single input variable and would therefore hold a static value each time the query is run and that the r1.session_cd in the secondary registration table is again a static value calculated from the r1.session_cd value.  My desired result (given 'Fall' as the input) would be:

```
    Student_number  name     reg_stsFall   reg_stsWinter
    012             James    active        active
    013             Sarah    withdrawn     active
```

Comment: As the answers are pointing out, you can't create column names at "runtime" for **any** (okay, maybe just most) RDBMS, including DB2.  Why do you feel you need this?  What problem are you trying to solve?  @Warren's answer using "current"/"next" columns is a good one in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is "pivot" the query results.

Unfortunately, this functionality isn't in the SQL standard and DB2 doesn't include any built in functionality to make this easy.

It can be done using standard SQL, but only with static column names.

For dynamic column names, you'd need to either dynamically build and execute a statement that uses static column names or use a reporting tool that can pivot the data itself.

If this is a one time deal and you have access to Excel, you could easily pull the data into an Excel pivot table.

Comment: I think I 'get' what you're suggesting as I routinely use 'Pivot' tables in Excel.  But I'm trying to create a ColumnName that is made up of input variables I specify instead of 'text'.  This isn't a one-off as I create alot of standard queries in my job and try to 'automate' as much as possible. If it were only as simple as three possible values, I'd just throw them into a case statement but unfortunately the session_cd is actually a five digit number made up of YYYYM and not as simple as just three possible values of fall/winter/summer :(  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need exactly those columns & column names, then you could build your query statement dynamically at run time into a character string, based on which session you are reporting, then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE that statement string.

Comment: Warren,  That's currently beyond my coding ability.  Do you have a sample or learning link you could share?

Comment: The software we use is called RocketShuttle and accepts simple SQL queries written against the DB2 and also allows you to compile/direct your SQL with Procedures.

Comment: How does it "accept" SQL queries? If it accepts them in a string variable, the column names would be generated by you as the string is built. If it has a different way of receiving statements, an example could be edited into the question to help us understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could put the values into appropriate columns, as long as you have some flexibility in the format of your result table.

First, let's put the session progression rules into a table, which may help here and there.

```
    Session_Progressions

    session   next_session
    --------  ------------
    'spring'  'summer'
    'summer'  'fall'
    'fall'    'winter'
    'winter'  'spring'
```

You might create a simple pivot query:

```
 select s.student_number, s.name,
        max( case when r.session_cd = 'spring'  
                    then r.registration_status
                    else null
             end )  as sts_spring,
        max( case when r.session_cd = 'summer'  
                    then r.registration_status
                    else null
             end )  as sts_summer,
        max( case when r.session_cd = 'fall'  
                    then r.registration_status
                    else null
             end )  as sts_fall,
        max( case when r.session_cd = 'winter'  
                    then r.registration_status
                    else null
             end )  as sts_winter,
   from student_nums s
   join session_progression t
         on  t.session = &session
   join registration_status r
         on  r.student_number = s.student_number
         and r.session_cd in (t.session, t.next_session)
   group by s.student_number, s.name
```

To give

```
    Student_number  name     sts_spring  sts_summer  sts_fall   sts_winter
    --------------  -------  ----------  ----------  ---------  ----------
    012             James                            active     active
    013             Sarah                            withdrawn  active
```

Alternatively you could add columns to indicate which sessions are being shown.

Now we can query:

```
 select s.student_number, s.name,
        r.session_cd           as curr_sessn,
        r.registration_status  as reg_sts_curr,
        r1.session_cd          as next_sessn,
        r1.registration_status as reg_sts_next
   from student_nums s
   join registration_status r
         on  r.session_cd = &session_cd
         and r.student_number = s.student_number
   join session_progression q
         on  r.session_cd = q.session       
   left join registration_status r1
         on  s.student_number = r1.student_number
         and r1.session_cd = q.next_session
```

To give

```
    Student_number  name     curr_sessn  reg_sts_curr  next_sessn  reg_sts_next
    --------------  -------  ----------  ------------  ----------  ------------
    012             James    fall        active        winter      active
    013             Sarah    fall        withdrawn     winter      active
```

Comment: I thought of that...  The problem is that I wish session was only three discrete values and then I could just use case statements to break it down into fall/winter/summer.  However, the session_cds are YYYYM where 20149 represents the session that begins in September of 2014.  What I really want is 'regsts || &session_cd' as my columnname.  This way if I'm using a base population from 20149, for example, they would show reg_sts_20149 and subsequent sessions, reg_sts_20151 and reg_sts_20155.  For now I'm just including the extra session column before each value.  Thanks!